# Get the list of names in json or xml Rest API in python

Tags: python, rest

I want REST API in python .When the request is made then I want all the list not the individual name.When the request is /getgamebyid/999 I am getting {"name": "third one", "release_date": "2013-10-28", "id": 999} but I want all the three names to get?What should I do?

```
from datetime import date
import tornado.escape
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class VersionHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        response = { 'version': '3.5.1',
                     'last_build':  date.today().isoformat() }
        self.write(response)

class GetGameByIdHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, id):
        response = { 'id': int(id),
                     'name': 'Crazy Game',
                     'release_date': date.today().isoformat(),
                                          'id': int(id),
                     'name': 'Second one',
                     'release_date': date.today().isoformat(),
                      'id': int(id),
                     'name': 'third one',
                     'release_date': date.today().isoformat() }

        self.write(response)


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/getgamebyid/([0-9]+)", GetGameByIdHandler),
    (r"/version", VersionHandler)
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: If you want it to be 'RESTful', then your call should probably be: `/games/999` for a particular game or `/games/` for the list.

Comment: I have to change the response as list?I tried I didn't get.Please help me to solve the issue.